# How should I get a role object from id?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How should I get a role object from id?
discord.js
I'm using

```
message.guild.roles.cache(toString(role id here))
```

Answer (score 3):

It's `cache.get` since `cache` is an instance of `Collection`

See [`<Collection>.get`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=get)

```js
message.guild.roles.cache.get(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest versions of discord.js, `<RoleManager>.cache` has the type of [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection)

So, to get a value stored in the collection, you'll be required to use the `.get("key")` method

Example:

```
const roleId = "your-role-id";
message.guild.roles.cache.get(roleId) // Returns <Role> object
```